# How is my code going over the recursion limit?

Tags: recursion

I don't know how my code is exceeding the recursion limit of 1024.

```
subdivide[verts_, n_] := (
  
  listOfPoints = Join[verts, {verts[[1]]}];
  
subdivisons = {}; 
    
For[i = 1, i < Length[listOfPoints], i++,
firstPoint = listOfPoints[[i]]; 
secondPoint = listOfPoints[[i + 1]];
x = (secondPoint[[1]] - firstPoint[[1]])/n;
y = (secondPoint[[2]] - firstPoint[[2]])/n;

For[j = 0, j < n, j++, 
 subdivisions = Join[subdivisions, {firstPoint + j {x, y}}];

];];



subdivisions;
)
```

Can someone please advise?

Comment: If you scrape-n-paste that into a notebook then I think you have a missing `]` somewhere to finish off your first `For`

Comment: Whoops, sorry. There was a ] there already, I didn't realize I didn't put it.

Comment: Wonderful. Next, do you expect your `subdivide` to return the value in `subdivisions`? If so then do you want that `;` at the end of that? Next, you might include one more line of code at the end, maybe something like `subdivide[{1,2,5},4]` or whatever would be good example input to your function. Next, you might try restarting MMA and running your code again. MMA has a cache and keeps track of previous assignments. Sometimes recursion errors are the result of a variable or function still being in cache. At the moment I'm getting an odd error about missing `)` that I haven't figured out.

Comment: subdivide is meant to return an evenly divided n-1 number of points in between the vertices provided, which are meant to be the vertices of a polygon. So, if it's given {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1} with n = 2, it'll give the halfway points between the vertices and end up with 8 coordinates.

Comment: Two typos.  First, `subdivisons = {};`  has a typo.  Second, remove the semicolon after the final `subdivisions;`

Comment: Can this whole thing just be replaced with Mathematica's built-in `Subdivide` ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that we use Mathematica's list manipulation capabilities to eliminate the `For` loops. Here's a `subdivide` function:

```
subdivide[verts_List, n_] := Flatten[Most[
  Transpose[
    Subdivide[Sequence @@ #, n] &/@ #]] &/@
  Transpose/@Partition[Append[verts, First@verts], 2, 1], 1]
```

**Example: each side of a square divided into two parts**

```
verts = CirclePoints[Sqrt[2], 4];
n = 2;
subdivisions = subdivide[verts, n];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], Polygon[verts],
  Red, PointSize[Scaled[.025]], Point[subdivisions]}, ImageSize -> 240]
```

[image: example 1]

**Example: each side of a random, five-sided polygon divided into four parts**

```
SeedRandom[2];
verts = RandomPolygon[5][[1]];
n = 4;
subdivisions = subdivide[verts, n];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], Polygon[verts],
  Red, PointSize[Scaled[.025]], Point[subdivisions]}, ImageSize -> 240]
```

[image: example 2]

**Details of the ***subdivide*** function**

The first step is to start with the vertices' coordinate pairs, `{{x1, y1}, ... {xn, yn}}`, then rearrange pairs into the `x` and `y` pair coordinates for the start and end points of each side. For example:

```
verts = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
Transpose/@Partition[Append[verts,First@verts], 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}}, {{x2, x3}, {y2, y3}}, {{x3, x1},{y3, y1}}}
> ```

Next, use [`Subdivide`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/Subdivide.html) to find the `n` subdivisions of each side, and `Transpose` back into `{x, y}` pairs. Because the last point of each line is the first point of the following line, use `Most` to remove the duplicates. `Flatten` gives the resulting list of points for `subdivisions`.